# Sort with values on top

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that lists a Facility, Housing Area, and a person's last name.

There are about 8 facilities. I want to sort by a specific facility and place on top to the top of the spreadsheet.

For example, say I have 100 rows where each row indicates a certain facility. Choose Queens Facility as a cell sorting criteria, and there are 10 rows with Queens Facility. I would like to sort all Queens Facility rows to be the first 10.

Here is the code. What is the other criteria to put a specific chosen facility on the top?

```
Sub SSSsort()

Dim lngRows As Long

lngRows = Range("AD65536").End(xlUp).Row

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("DumpTab").Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1:A" & lngRows), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B1:B" & lngRows), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("E1:E" & lngRows), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        '
        .SetRange Range("A1:AD" & lngRows)
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Here is a sample table in EXCEL:

[image: Sample Data]

Comment: Note that without access to your data, we are not able to see what column corresponds to what criterion. Regarding your question, if you want the rows grouped by facility, your first sorting criterion needs to be the facility column. This will only sort them alphabetically, though. If you want a different order, you'll need to look into user-defined lists. You could also try recording a macro while manually setting up a sorting with a custom list.

Comment: I added the sample data for your review

Comment: Perhaps a new column wherein you can put a number (through VBA), "0" for the facility you want on top, and "1" for everyone else. Then your sort is that column, then the facility.

Comment: The macro recorder should solve all your problems. Record yourself using the Excel Sort feature then look at the code it generated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the `CustomOrder` property of the `SortFields.Add` Method.

For example, if your Facilities were "Jacks Facility", "Queens Facility", "Kings Facility" and "Aces Facility", and the Facility was in Column D, then you could use this code to sort in that order:

```
.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("D1:D" & lngRows), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
    CustomOrder:="Jacks Facility,Queens Facility,Kings Facility,Aces Facility", _
    DataOption:=xlSortNormal
```

(The [`Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/join-function) function will make it easy to collapse an array into a text list, if needed)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by recording a macro:

```
'Filter Criteria based on Chosen Facility:
Sheets("DumpTab").Range("$A$1:$AX$8228").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Facility

'Sort based on housing unit:
Sheets("DumpTab").Range("$A$1:$AX$8228").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=HousingUnit
```

All you need to do is add the two lines together and you sort based on 2 criteria.